# Proving that a matrix is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove that $A^TB^TBA$ is symmetric, but I am having hard time applying concepts.

I should prove that
$(A^TB^TBA)^T$ $=$ $A^TB^TBA$, but how can I apply product rule like $(AB)^T$ = $B^TA^T$ to prove the above relation?

Comment: $$((AB)C)^T = C^T(AB)^T$$

Comment: Use the associative law for matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're confused about how to apply $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ to $A^TB^TBA$, try grouping terms:

$$(A^TB^TBA)^T=(((A^TB^T)B)A)^T=A^T((A^TB^T)B)^T=A^TB^T(A^TB^T)^T=A^TB^T(B^T)^T(A^T)^T=A^TB^TBA.$$

Maybe you can see a pattern that,
$$(A_1A_2...A_{n-1}A_n)^T=A_n^TA_{n-1}^T...A_2^TA_1^T,$$
can you prove this using induction?

Comment: I just wanted to be clear since it seems that OP is new to linear algebra.

Comment: ...the order of the last two

Comment: oh it was a typo, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $A^tB^t=(BA)^t$.  But for any $C$, $C^tC$ is symmetric.   For, $(C^tC)^t=C^t(C^t)^t=C^tC$.  $\therefore A^tB^tBA$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Or, when grouping two and two, 
$$\big(\left(A^TB^T\right)\left(AB\right)\big)^T=\left(AB\right)^T\left(A^TB^T\right)^T=\left(B^TA^T\right)(BA)=B^TA^TBA.$$

Answer (score 0):

$(A^TB^TBA)^T=A^TB^T(B^T)^T(A^T)^T=A^TB^TBA$

Really nothing to add here.